# Make use of an extra router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

At my home, I have a modem that connects the ADSL linked to a Linksys router. However I also have one router from Telefonica which I would like to use with my setup to increase the signal range. How can I set that up?

Comment: It won't increase signal range per say, but you can cable it to another part of your home and use it as an access point in order to increase coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You can flash the second router with ddwwrt and use it as a wireless repeater.

More details can be found here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater